# SELinux: determine directory of denied file creation

Tags: linux, selinux

Using SELinux, I got this AVC:

> type=AVC msg=audit(1472867145.344:215): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=2434 comm="google-chrome" name="63" scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unconfined_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

Is there any way to determine the directory in which Chrome is trying to create file `63`?

**EDIT**: I tried adding `audit=1` to the kernel command line as suggested [her](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/sec-sel-analystcontrol.html), but it didn't get me any additional info.

Comment: Does `ausearch -m avc -ts 1472867145.344` help? Or perhaps `ausearch -a 215` ?

Comment: @StephenHarris No, didn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Apparently it is a bug, however it does not affect the behaviour of Chrome. I found an entry for the bug here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1345836<br>
According to the report the full path of the file is `/dev/63`

Comment: @Fisian It's actually [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1370475), attempting to open `/dev/fd/63`.  Appears to be a kernel bug.